# Massively run scripts on Azure machines

Tags: security, azure, automation

We have a large Azure infrastructure to maintain. The Azure Security Centre reported a number of security configuration issue (`problem X`) that we have to mitigate.

Some of them are quite easy to address, **such as** ensuring the `0400` permission of `/etc/shadow` file, the presence of a `cron.allow` file, the proper file permissions on `/boot` or other directories. So, with the scope of the *issues that can be addressed by running shell commands*, I would like to massively run a shell script on all or part of the Azure infrastructure (`problem Y` asked here).

What are the proper tools to handle this kind of activity?

We are going to evaluate `Logic Apps`, but there seems apparently no clear way to run shell commands on a machine.

We could possibly use a Powerhsell/AZ Cli script that cycles over the list of the affected machines (copied and pasted from the Log Analytics query result).

To give a bit more of context, we are now only examining Linux issues in this session, as a number of Windows configuration issues can be fixed by properly setting the group policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer of your problem is **ansible**. Take it a look and read the docs: https://www.ansible.com/

A little introduction to it. You will need an ansible host. On it you will write a "script" (a playbook) that can work with shell. Ansible will connect to all hosts you've configurated and execute the "script" that you've written simultaneously.